# How can I remove the output cache on a per-user basis in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using `VaryByCustom` to create an output cache on a per-browser and per-user basis:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 6000, VaryByParam = "*", VaryByCustom="browser;userName")]
```

(I've overridden `GetVaryByCustomString()` to make this work.)

I need to be able to remove a single user's output cache, without invalidating the output cache of different users, if possible.  I've read about `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem()`, but that works by removing the output cache based on path.  Is there any way to do this based on the VaryByCustom string?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the advantage of `VaryByCustom` property in `[OutputCache]` by overriding `HttpApplication.GetVaryByCustomString` and check `HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated.`

This is what I will create in Global.asax.cs file:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
        if (custom == "UserName")
        {
            if (context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return context.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            return null;
        }

        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
    }
```

And then use it in OutputCache attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByCustom = "UserName")]
public ActionResult Profiles()
{
    //...
}
```

but be careful that the username should be immutable in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the user in the parameters and then it would be per-user through the VaryByParam.

Comment: That would work, but I don't want to add an otherwise unnecessary query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use

```
Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom(string custom);
```

in an ActionFilter the you can build up the string including browser version and user

Comment: That's essentially what I'm already doing.  What I need is to be able to reset the cache for a user, even if they are using the same browser.