# How to use: HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem when using varyByCustom

Tags: asp.net, redis, outputcache, azure-redis-cache

I have implemented the Redis OutputCache (Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider) using the Azure Redis service.

I have found similar unanswered / unsolved questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186327/how-can-i-remove-the-output-cache-on-a-per-user-basis-in-asp-net-mvc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288600/how-to-evict-from-output-cache-when-using-varybycustom-for-multitenant-app).

On top of the pages need to cache:
    `<%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="*" Duration="600" %>`

After access a random page and I check the key in Redis database is has saved like: /_a2/monitor.aspx

So running the below line of code, will remove this cache item (and it worked).

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/monitor.aspx", "RedisOutputCache")
```

Now I have updated the same page adding the varyByCustom the the OutputCache directive:
    `<%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="*" varyByCustom="userhash" Duration="600" %>`

Now accessing the page and checking the key in Redis database it is saved like: /_a2/monitor.aspxHQFCNuserhashVcc6ef5b7173286704cef942d5577b88bd81f2cce71a0dcdc8676d3a815e68b59DE

You see the added userhash hash value, this is nice and worked as expected.

But now here comes the problem: How do I clear this cache item.

This is not working:

```
`HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/monitor.aspx", "RedisOutputCache")`
```

Also tried:
    `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/monitor.aspx?userhash=cc6ef5b7173286704cef942d5577b88bd81f2cce71a0dcdc8676d3a815e68b59", "RedisOutputCache")`

And also tried:
    `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/monitor.aspx {userhash:cc6ef5b7173286704cef942d5577b88bd81f2cce71a0dcdc8676d3a815e68b59}", "RedisOutputCache")`

Also tried using some of the below options in combination of the above code:

```
Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("userhash")
Response.AddCacheItemDependency("action")
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Item("action") = "test"
Response.Cache.VaryByParams("userhash") = True
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/monitor.aspx")
```

Is there an way to remove this cache item on using the varyByCustom option?

I don't use the system.web.mvc object. So I can not access this object for URL helper.

Any help is most welcome!

Joël

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I tried to implement my [OutputCacheProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.aspx) to store cache into files to test this issue on my side. Here is my test result, you could refer to it.

**OutputCache** of my Monitor.aspx

`<%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="None" Duration="60" Location="Server" %>`

When accessing the above page, I would get the following log from my OutputFileCacheProvider as follows:

[image]

And the current DateTime string would be refreshed in my monitor.aspx page after I have accessed another .aspx to clear the cache.

`<%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="*" Duration="60" VaryByCustom="userhash" Location="Server" %>`

**Note:** The same way to call `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/monitor.aspx")` for cleaning cache from another .aspx endpoint.

[image]

Both `VaryByParam` and `varyByCustom` could work as expected on my side. I assumed that you could add log within your OutputCacheProvider and try to find whether you have missed something.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for your reply. I'am not sure if the Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider has debug logging options. But I notice something. In the second image the cache items where you have usage the VaryByCustom="userhash" parameter, are still not removed. It removed the items white-out the userhash. So I think this is something it's not provide in the RedisOutputCacheProvider. Thx! Jo

Comment: Have you tried to change `VaryByParam` as `None` while using VaryByCustom as follows: <%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="None" varyByCustom="userhash" Duration="600" %>